# Pusher with vue and Laravel works only by dashboard event creator

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher

I'm integrating the provider Pusher to broadcast data in my SPA (vue/laravel).

The frontend (Vue) is working well if I test it sending an event from the dashboard Pusher event-creator; all my browsers received the event. Good!

But... if I send the event by my backend no event occurred.

Here my codes:

**frontend** (vue)

```
        ...

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');

        channel.bind('hello', function (data) {
            console.log("I got...");
            console.log(data);
           // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
```

**The controller** (backend)

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Events\hello;

class HelloController extends Controller{
  //
   public function hello(REQUEST $request){
   event(new hello('hello world'));
  }
}
```

**The event**: (backed)

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;

  class hello implements ShouldBroadcast{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

   public $message;

   public function __construct($message){
      $this->message = $message;
   }

   public function broadcastOn()    {
    return ['my-channel'];
}

   public function broadcastAs(){
      return 'hello';
   }
 }
```

[EDIT]

The console browser report on loading page:

```
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected with new socket ID 12 1.33
 app.js:1 Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":    {"channel":"my-channel"}}
 app.js:1 Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"my-channel","data":{}}
 app.js:1 Pusher : No callbacks on my-channel for pusher:subscription_succeeded
```

[EDIT 2]
I realized I can't run queue on my shared server so I extended the interface from  ShouldBroadcast to **ShouldBroadcastNow** interface:

```
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;

 class hello implements ShouldBroadcastNow{...
```

[EDIT 3]

I notice my **.ENV** <--------------  has a "wrong" BROADCAST_DRIVER

> BROADCAST_DRIVER=log

So I switch to

> BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

But... nothing works anymore:

> **Class 'Pusher\Pusher' not found**

I have done:

- Pusher is installed by composer (required and installed)
- config/app aliases updated with  'Pusher'    =>  Pusher\Pusher::class
- laravel cache removed
  -

But it not fixed... yet.

Can you help me to debug it? Thanks